# Why does non-autonomous generate an extra dimension?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've colloquially seen non-autonomous ordinary differential equations described as having an "extra dimension" due to the non-autonomy which I think makes sense, but I also don't know why that makes sense or what the technical explanation for that is. Is there a formalization of this?

Comment: It's nothing more than the substitution $x_{n+1} = t \implies \dot{x}_{n+1} = 1$ to superficially get rid of the $t$

Comment: Okay, so suppose one has the differential equation $y'(t) = t*y(t).$ You're saying this can be interpreted as a system $x(t) = t, t'(t) = 1,$ giving $y' = xy, x' = 1?$ But you already know $x$ explicitly.

Comment: The generalizable system formulation would be $$\dot{\mathbf{x}}\equiv\begin{pmatrix} \dot{x}_1 \\ \dot{x}_2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} x_1x_2 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \equiv \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})$$ which is now autonomous.